# How to make retail-friendly adhesive hang tab packaging

Tags: paper, adhesives, printing

So I have looked all over the interwebs for how to make (or buy) a paper-backed adhesive plastic package with a retail-friendly hang tab.  This is exactly what I'm looking for, except that I'd like to print my own info on the paper backing:

[image]

Any ideas on how to buy/make this en masse?  Thanks so much!

Comment: How "en masse" are you talking? I assume that these are purchased as a custom order from a supplier.

Comment: @Catija about 1000 packets.  I just don't know what this is called and where to get them from, and if I need to make them myself

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really mystified as to how this is an arts & crafts question.

Comment: @JohnCavan sorry if it wasn't obvious to you, but I was thinking of making these from scratch (hang tabs, adhesive, printed cardboard, plastic clamshells) and I didn't know where to start.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Making them from scratch doesn't necessarily mean it's a craft. Reading "buy/make this en masse" implies that this is for general retail usage and that there is no craft aspect to it. If it make it from scratch is the sole criteria to define an art/craft, then just about everything is. That's rather broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology that you're missing is "[Blister packaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister_pack)". This is specific to a molded plastic front with a cardboard backing.  The kind in your image is heat sealed in place.

There's also "slide blister packaging" which has a two-part construction with a plastic front that has flanges that hold the cardboard in place on three sides and a staple (usually) keeps it from sliding out of place in the store.

Here's an [example](http://www.aapack.com/products-and-solutions/thermoformed-packaging/blister-packaging/) of a company who makes them and the sorts of packs they offer.

> Thermoformed blisters can be:
>
> - Sealed to the front of a graphics card (seal blister)
> - Trapped between two graphics cards (trapped or captive blister)
> - Given flanges for a card to slide into (slide blister)
> - Welded to another blister with a finished appearance (welded blister)
> - Placed inside a carton, box or clamshell (tray)
> - Stacked on top of identical blisters to transport parts within or between manufacturing facilities (returnable tray)
> - Sealed to a lidstock material that can be peeled or punctured (pharmaceutical blister)

[image: Thermoformed Blister Pack]

Answer (score 0):

The type of package you're looking at is called a **clamshell package** or a **clamshell blister package**.

They come in a variety of sizes. Suppliers will have different dimensions for height and width of the whole package, plus height/width/depth of the "blister" area where the product can actually sit. This lets you choose how much space you want to give to product and how much you want for branding materials.

A quick look at several different bulk suppliers, and estimates of buying bulk amounts of small quantities, shows that these packages will run you $200-300+ USD for the minimum 1,000 quantity you require. Perhaps you can find lower prices if you search more thoroughly than I did.

Once you obtain the packages, you can measure the exact dimensions for the print you want to insert. You could possibly print the design at home on a printer, even using adhesive-backed printing paper, or you could take it to a shop and have it done. You'd provide them the file you want printed, dimension specs, and quantity and they'd take care of it.

If you use normal cardstock, and don't want it to shift, you could glue it to the back of the clamshell yourself. However, most items in clamshells that I've ever purchased haven't ever bothered to adhere the insert to the plastic. So, it comes out, which can actually be helpful if it includes instructions.

Comment: right on!  I'll look for a lower price.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You might find that producers can print for less than what you have to pay if you do your own prints. Often they offer the combination because they make money on one and are willing to do without a lot of profits on the other, and they do print in huge numbers, cutting their costs.